# Unable to pass fetched firebase data into functional component

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

New to react native (expo), and I'm trying to figure out how to pass through some data I've pulled from firestore into a functional component

```
let tileItems = [];

interface LocationTile{
  placeID: string;
  imgURL: string;
  destination: string;
}

const LocationTile = [{
  placeID: 'id123',
  imgURL: 'https://img2.storyblok.com/1000x1118/filters:format(webp)/f/51678/1000x1118/603ad64c98/itinerary-hero-mobile-1-lapb.jpg',
  destination: 'PARIS'
}];

const data = LocationTile;
const user = auth.currentUser

const GetDestinations = async ()=> {
  const destinationsCollection = collection(db, "/users/" + user.uid + "/Destinations")
  const tripsSnapshot = await getDocs(destinationsCollection);
  const tripsList = tripsSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  
  LocationTile.push({
    placeID: tripsList[0].placeID,
    imgURL: tripsList[0].imgURL,
    destination: tripsList[0].text}
  )
  console.log(VisionTile) // line 38
  return data;
}

const VisionCard:FC<{item: LocationTile }> = ({item}) => {

///
///
console.log(LocationTile); // line 49
///
///
```

I can see that I am successfully pushing the first result from firebase into the `LocationTile` array, but the functional component doesn't see the appended item.

Result from `console.log(VisionTile)` on line 38

```
Array [
  Object {
    "destination": "PARIS",
    "imgURL": "https://img2.storyblok.com/1000x1118/filters:format(webp)/f/51678/1000x1118/603ad64c98/itinerary-hero-mobile-1-lapb.jpg",
    "placeID": "id123",
  },
  Object {
    "destination": "Venice",
    "imgURL": "https://img2.storyblok.com/1000x1118/filters:format(webp)/f/51678/1000x1118/603ad64c98/itinerary-hero-mobile-1-lapb.jpg",
    "placeID": "ChIJKUgTyxaqfkcREH-QFYcJBwM",
  },
]
```

result of `console.log(LocationTile)` on line 49

```
Array [
  Object {
    "destination": "PARIS",
    "imgURL": "https://img2.storyblok.com/1000x1118/filters:format(webp)/f/51678/1000x1118/603ad64c98/itinerary-hero-mobile-1-lapb.jpg",
    "placeID": "id123",
  },
]
```

I am unsure how to properly load the functional component only after the data pull from firebase is complete. Moving `const VisionCard:FC<{item: LocationTile }> = ({item}) => {` has only produced reference errors later in the code when I try to move it to another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels somewhat sloppy to me, but it got the job done.

```
const [tileItems, updateTiles] = useState(data)
      const [pullComplete, updatePullComplete] = useState(false)
  
      useEffect(() => {
        GetDestinations();
        setTimeout(() => {
          if(pullComplete === false){
            console.log("pulled")
            updateTiles(data)
            updatePullComplete(true)
          }
          updatePullComplete(true)
        }, 500);
      });
```